# Python: find closest string (from a list) to another string

Tags: python, string, algorithm, list

Let's say I have a `string` `"Hello"` and a list

```
words = ['hello', 'Hallo', 'hi', 'house', 'key', 'screen', 'hallo','question', 'Hallo', 'format']
```

How can I find the `n words` that are the closest to `"Hello"` and present in the list `words` ?

In this case, we would have `['hello', 'hallo', 'Hallo', 'hi', 'format'...]`

So the strategy is to sort the list words from the closest word to the furthest.

I thought about something like this

```
word = 'Hello'
for i, item in enumerate(words):
    if lower(item) > lower(word):
      ...
```

but it's very slow in large lists.

**UPDATE**
`difflib` works but it's very slow also. (`words list` has 630000+ words inside (sorted and one per line)). So checking the list takes 5 to 7 seconds for every search for closest word!

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something like editing distance or Levinshtein distance?

Comment: Exactly, this largely depends on what your definition of '_closest_' is.

Comment: Are the 630,000 words sorted? Are they in a file, one word per line?

Comment: How do you intend to define 'closest'? In your sample code, you're using a lexicographic comparison, but that ranks 'hermitage' as a better match for 'hello' than 'jello' is.

Comment: Did you find an efficient solution for 6M+ dictionary items? I'm stocked here as well.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Use [`difflib.get_close_matches`](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches).

```
>>> words = ['hello', 'Hallo', 'hi', 'house', 'key', 'screen', 'hallo', 'question', 'format']
>>> difflib.get_close_matches('Hello', words)
['hello', 'Hallo', 'hallo']
```

Please look at the documentation, because the function returns 3 or less closest matches by default.

Comment: Just a quick FYI: `difflib.get_close_matches("Hallo", words, len(words), 0)` would give all matches :)

Comment: The Levenshtein difference can be used as well. There is a good python implementation http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/

Comment: difflib works but it's very slow also. (words list has 630000+ words inside). So checking the list takes 5 to 7 seconds for every search for closest word!

Comment: @Laura There is a difference between being slow and taking a long time. 7 seconds might be a long time but it might not be slow.

Comment: @Oleh, I was wondering if you happen to know if there is an alternative of `difflib.get_close_matches` that return the list indexes, not the strings. I posted [another question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50861237/is-there-an-alternative-to-difflib-get-close-matches-that-returns-the-list-i)

Comment: Hi @NiklasB, in this case how can I get only one closest word

Comment: Can someone point out to algorithm behind `difflib`? I am curious to read about it.

Comment: I am putting a string from the list but it isn't returning something. Could it be because I am using non-english strings/characters? I have tried also lowering the cutoff

Answer (score 35):

There is an awesome article with a complete source code (21 lines) provided by Peter Norvig on spelling correction.

http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html

The idea is to build all possible edits of your word,

```
hello - helo   - deletes    
hello - helol  - transpose    
hello - hallo  - replaces    
hello - heallo - inserts    


def edits1(word):
   splits     = [(word[:i], word[i:]) for i in range(len(word) + 1)]
   deletes    = [a + b[1:] for a, b in splits if b]
   transposes = [a + b[1] + b[0] + b[2:] for a, b in splits if len(b)>1]
   replaces   = [a + c + b[1:] for a, b in splits for c in alphabet if b]
   inserts    = [a + c + b     for a, b in splits for c in alphabet]
   return set(deletes + transposes + replaces + inserts)
```

Now, look up each of these edits in your list.

Peter's article is a great read and worth reading.

Answer (score 2):

Create a sorted list of your words and use the [bisect module](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html) to identify the point in the sorted list where your word would fit according to the sorting order. Based on that position you can give the k nearest neighbours above and below to find the 2k closest words.

Comment: Are you sure this will work? I don't think lexicographical order is what OP wants...

Comment: Considering the code snippet from the question, such a simple solution could be all that is required.

Comment: This won't work if possible spelling mistakes are to be considered, especially if mistakes are made at the beginning of the word. But a good solution for correct words indeed.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this should not work. For example: `zoom` and `boom` have much similar spelling, but they will be situated at the two opposite ends of your sorted list. How do you match them?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at this answer for getting a closest match from a list or possible alternatives of

```
difflib.get_close_matches
```

I found [Amjith's answer based on Peter Norwig's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10020219/1660759) and thought it might be a good replacement. Before I realised it might not be quite much suited for my use case, I had made a class out of it. So this is a version of spell where you can use it for different set of words. Maybe best use can be for population name matching.

```
import re
from collections import Counter

def words(text): return re.findall(r'\w+', text.lower())

# WORDS = Counter(words(open('big.txt').read()))


class WordMatcher:

    def __init__(self, big_text):
        self.WORDS=Counter(words(big_text))
        self.N = sum(self.WORDS.values())

    def P(self, word):
        "Probability of `word`."
        return self.WORDS[word] / self.N

    def correction(self, word):
        "Most probable spelling correction for word."
        return max(self.candidates(word), key=self.P)

    def candidates(self, word):
        "Generate possible spelling corrections for word."
        return (self.known([word]) or self.known(self.edits1(word)) or self.known(self.edits2(word)) or [word])

    def known(self, words):
        "The subset of `words` that appear in the dictionary of WORDS."
        return set(w for w in words if w in self.WORDS)

    def edits1(self, word):
        "All edits that are one edit away from `word`."
        letters    = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
        splits     = [(word[:i], word[i:])    for i in range(len(word) + 1)]
        deletes    = [L + R[1:]               for L, R in splits if R]
        transposes = [L + R[1] + R[0] + R[2:] for L, R in splits if len(R)>1]
        replaces   = [L + c + R[1:]           for L, R in splits if R for c in letters]
        inserts    = [L + c + R               for L, R in splits for c in letters]
        return set(deletes + transposes + replaces + inserts)

    def edits2(self, word):
        "All edits that are two edits away from `word`."
        return (e2 for e1 in self.edits1(word) for e2 in self.edits1(e1))
```

Answer (score -4):

maybe [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) can help you .

you have a heap named `Heap` that until it's size is less than `n` , you insert words into the `Heap` using function `close` [shows this string is closer than another string or not] .

this method can help you when `n` is small :)

```
Heap = []
for word in words:
    if len(Heap)<n:
       Heap.insert(word)
    else
       if close(word,Heap[0]): # it means Heap[0] is the nth farthest word until now
             Heap.pop():
             Heap.insert(word)
```

Comment: needs implementation of 'close'

Comment: This is just a datastructure to hold the words, it explains nothing about computing similarity.