# Python: Find closest match of multiple words in text file

Tags: python, parsing

I need to parse multiple financial statement .txt files similarly to this [one](http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000104746904035975/0001047469-04-035975.txt). The .txt files do not have standardized format. However, they have similar headings. My objective is to extract the section of the .txt files that starts with the following keywords `['Item', '7', 'Management', 'Analysis']` and ends with `['Item', '8', 'Financial', 'Statements']`. The order of the words in both list matter and `['Item', '7', 'Management', 'Analysis']` comes before `['Item', '8', 'Financial', 'Statements']`.

What I have in mind is to start with:

```
fdir = open('C:\\0001193125-13-416534.txt','r')
lines = fdir.readlines()
```

and loop over each line in `lines` and use [`difflib.get_close_matches`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018679/python-find-closest-string-from-a-list-to-another-string) to find the above keywords. However, I have two issues: (1) How can I use `difflib` to search for more than one word? (2) I know that `difflib` will simply extract the match word, but how can I use it to find the `index` (location in the list `lines`) of where exactly in `lines` are located these words?

Let me add a third issue: Is using `.readlines()` the appropriate way to read the txt file and start searching for the match words or should I simply use `.read()`?

Comment: Easy with `re` module. Use `.read()` to suck everything in to a string. Then use `re.findall() or re.finditer()`. Your pattern is  simple.

Comment: Can you make it clearer if you are looking for any of the starts or all/some of them (possibly in a different order) followed by any/all of the finishes and if which finish is related to which start - i.e. if the first is "Item 8" then the last will be "Item 7", etc.

Comment: @SteveBarnes Yes the order matter. I will clarify this in the question. Thank you

Comment: no standardized format ? ;) it's 99.9% of html only somes lines in the begin are not,remove them and use an html parser for extract what you want. If you need information from the begin (non html) regexp can be nice, but it can also be complex depends of the task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re` here with f.read().

f.read() return a string whereas f.readlines() returns a list.

```
import re
x=f.read()
print re.findall(r"Item(?:(?!Item).)*7(?:(?!Item|7).)*Management(?:(?!Item|7|Management).)*Analysis[\s\S]*Item(?:(?!Item).)*8(?:(?!Item|8).)*Financial(?:(?!Item|8|Financial).)*Statements",x)
```

Comment: Oh wow! Seems to work well! Question, where online I can get the details on all the `(?:(?!|\s\S))` and their meanings?

Comment: @Plug4 here http://regex101.com/r/aE3eI9/1 try some inputs and see the outputs as well...the explanation is on the right side :)

Comment: can Regex handle breakpoint? What if for one line I have `Item` and on the next line `7` and not `Item 7` on the same line?

Comment: @Plug4 if that's the case add `DOTALL` flag :)

Comment: perfect got it! I did `re.findall(r"Item(?:(?!Item).)*7(?:(?!Item|7).)*Management(?:(?!Item|7|Management).)*Analysis[\s\S]*Item(?:(?!Item).)*8(?:(?!Item|8).)*Financial(?:(?!Item|8|Financial).)*Statements",x, re.DOTALL)`