# Iterate through List Python

Tags: python

I am trying to see if a string I have is similar to any of the strings in a dictionary in python. When I am looking for exact matches, I can do this:

```
stringList = []
if (myString in stringList):
    #do something
```

Looking for similar matches using Python Levenshtein is the best I can come up with (I'm sure with some errors).

```
stringList = []
for i in range(len(stringList)):
    if distance(myString, stringList[i]) < 2:
        #do something
    else:
        #do something else
```

Is there a better way? Thanks.

Comment: how does this comes under dictionary when you are using only list in example provide sample input and expected output

Comment: You are welcome but can you provide sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's more pythonic like this :

```
stringList = []
for item in stringList:
    if distance(myString, item) < 2:
        #do something
    else:
        #do something else
```

best regard

Answer (score 2):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/10018734/4941367

Use the `difflib` module.

```
difflib.get_close_matches(myString, myList)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care what string is close enough, you can use the [`min`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#min) function:

```
if min(distance(x, myString) for x in stringList) < 2:
    # do something
```