# Python: difflib.get_close_matches comparing modified text but returning original

Tags: python, nlp, data-analysis, data-cleaning, difflib

I extracted a list of words from a text, but during text preprocessing I have lowercased everything for easier comparison.

My question is how to make the extracted words in the list appear as they exactly appeared in the original text?

I have tried to first tokenize the original text, and then find the closest matches in thise tokenized list to the word list I have extracted from the text. I used the each of the following for finding the closest matches:

1. nltk.edit_distance
2. difflib.get_close_matches

But neither of them worked as I wanted. They extract somehow similar words but not exactly as they appear in the original text. I think the problem is that these methods treat lowercased, and uppercased words differently.

> Words extracted can be unigram, bigram up to 5-gram.

Example:

I have extracted the following bigram from text **[rfid alert]**, but in original text it appeared like this **[RFID alert]**.

After using

`difflib.get_close_matches('rfid alert', original_text_unigram_tokens_list)`

it's output was **[profile Caller]**  and not **[RFID alert]**. That is because python is case-sensitive. I think it found that the bigram in `original_text_unigram_tokens_list` with the least number of different characters from **[rfid alert]** is **[profile Caller]** so it returned **[profile Caller]**.

Therefore my question is: Is there any ready method or any workaround I could do to return the original form of the ngram as it appeared in text exactly? For instance, I want to get **[RFID alert]** instead of **[profile Caller]** in the above example, and so on.

I appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide some examples (data)?

Comment: Sorry for not giving an example. I have updated my question to include a clear example. If the above example isn't clear enough, you can tell to provide more examples. Thank you. @sophros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50861237/is-there-an-alternative-to-difflib-get-close-matches-that-returns-indexes-l) you can take and modify the source code of [`difflib.get_close_matches`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/difflib.py#L698) and adapt it to your need.

Modifications I made:

- `cutoff` default value raised to 0.99 (theoretically it could even be 1.0 but to ensure numerical errors do not influence the results I am passing a smaller number).
- `s.set_seq1(x.lower())` - so that the comparison was done between lower-cased strings (but returned original `x`)

Full code of the modified function:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher, _nlargest  # necessary imports of functions used by modified get_close_matches

def get_close_matches_lower(word, possibilities, n=3, cutoff=0.99):
    if not n >  0:
        raise ValueError("n must be > 0: %r" % (n,))
    if not 0.0 <= cutoff <= 1.0:
        raise ValueError("cutoff must be in [0.0, 1.0]: %r" % (cutoff,))
    result = []
    s = SequenceMatcher()
    s.set_seq2(word)
    for x in possibilities:
        s.set_seq1(x.lower())  # lower-case for comparison
        if s.real_quick_ratio() >= cutoff and \
           s.quick_ratio() >= cutoff and \
           s.ratio() >= cutoff:
            result.append((s.ratio(), x))

    # Move the best scorers to head of list
    result = _nlargest(n, result)
    # Strip scores for the best n matches
    return [x for score, x in result]
```

And the result on the example you gave:

```
print(get_close_matches_lower('rfid alert', ['profile Caller','RFID alert']))
```

Printing:

```
['RFID alert']
```

Comment: I really want to thank you very much for this great modification to the function. This function is really working very well with me when I tested it. But I think due to some text cleaning issues in my text, sometimes I need to change the cutoff to 0.6 instead of 0.99 to avoid the case of the function returning an empty list, and it does a very great job and gets the match. Thank you again. @sophros

Comment: @Bahgat - glad to hear and happy to help. Would you be so kind as to mark the question as answered by clicking the grey tick mark besides my answer? Much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me. Of course, I did it now. And thank you very much again for your great help. @sophros