# How to clean data having spelling mistakes

Tags: data-munging

I have data as below:

```
Carepnter
Carpentor
Labourer
Labor
Labour
Housewife
House Wife
housewife.
```

I want to clean data and rectify the spelling mistakes but not manually because its a huge data. Due to spelling mistakes these 50/60 occupations have become around 2000.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to find strings that are close to the actual occupation, for instance carpenter. 
Then you can try to find the closest n-matches to it.

Another question on here also dealt with finding similar strings ([Python: find closest string (from a list) to another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018679/python-find-closest-string-from-a-list-to-another-string)) and the solutions from the answers for you could be either:

1. [difflib.get_close_matches](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches)
2. [Spelling corrector](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html)