# Find closest match in another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, fuzzywuzzy

Is there a way to find the closest match to a string? The df has 2 independent columns. user_input is a column with 1000 non-emptyrows. Since there are only 20 possible_fruits, possible_fruits has 980 empty rows.

```
df
    user_input    possible_fruits
     aapl            apple
     applee          pear
     aaaple          banana
...
```

Expected Output

```
user_input  closest_match_in_possible_fruits
aapl            apple      
applee          apple      
aaaple          apple
```

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018679/python-find-closest-string-from-a-list-to-another-string/10018734

Answer (score 1):

Try using http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches

```py
difflib.get_close_matches(user_input1, possible_fruits)
```

For the columns do

```
for i in df:
   answer = difflib.get_close_matches(df['user_input'][i], df['possible_fruits'])
   print (answer)
```

Edit:

```py
user_input = df['user_input']
possible_fruits = df['possible_fruits']

for i in user_input:
    answer = difflib.get_close_matches(user_input[i], possible_fruits)
    print(answer)
```

Comment: When I do ```difflib.get_close_matches(df['user_input'], df['possible_fruits'])``` I get [ ] as the output

Comment: You need to use a for loop to loop through the list

Comment: But the df has 2 columns. Should I convert each column into a list?

Comment: KeyError: 'user_input''

Comment: I changed it again, changing the df['possible_fruits'][i] to just df['possible_fruits']