# how do i normalize strings according to a default list?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-preprocessing

I have a list with strings that are basically names of programs that doens't follow a formatting pattern, such as: `[program1, prOgrAM2, program3_US, ..., progrAmN]`. This list is a reference and should not be altered.

I am working with a `pandas.DataFrame` which is data collected from a .csv file and there is a column `target_program`. This column has values contained in my list, but not guaranteed it follows the same pattern. I would like to normalize this column according to the list, ie:

```
List
[program1, program_2, ...]

Column
[prograM1, progrAm1, PROGRAM2, proGram2, ....]

=>

Column after normalization:
[program1, program1, program_2, program_2, ...]
```

Thanks

Comment: did u check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018679/python-find-closest-string-from-a-list-to-another-string

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what i need. Sorry, i couldn't find it before.