# Can you make an if statement that accepts any combination of upper and lowercase letters in a specific input string in Python such as "You", or "YUo"?

Tags: python, letter

Can you make an if statement that accepts any combination of upper and lowercase letters in a specific input string in Python such as "You", or "YUo"?

Comment: You can use `lower` or `casefold`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold

Comment: @j1-lee I think he is also asking for something like an "elastic search" to account for misspelled words also? [Similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018679/python-find-closest-string-from-a-list-to-another-string)

Comment: Is "YUo" a typo? Like, is it supposed to be "YoU"? Or is the U really supposed to be in a different place?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [How do I do a case-insensitive string comparison?](/q/319426/4518341), [Checking if two strings contain the same characters, not considering their frequencies](/q/13667113/4518341)

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You could modify the string so that everything is lowercase like this:

```
user_input = input("Say something: ")

if user_input.lower() == "you":
    print("hi")
```

Answer (score 0):

Any combination can be achieved with set()

```
input_str = 'YUo' # 'You' 'oYu'
match_str = 'you'
if set(input_str.lower()) == set(match_str):
    print('matched')
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use ternary operators to check this like following:

```
True if False not in [True if (i.lower() in y.lower()) else False for i in x] else False
```

Comment: These conditional expressions are totally redundant. Either way, it looks like you want to use `any()`/`all()` instead.